# How to remove garbage value from a file name which has been created by using createTempFile() method

Tags: java

I have used File.createTempFile() method to create temp file but as its output it appends the garbage value with the file name too. I used the method for uploading zipfile, but unable to delete those appended garbage value. For further functionality I need the exact name of file.

Kindly help...

---

Highly appreciate your response.
My concern is, as code stated by niiraj874u, I am getting the the File name : tmp4501156806082176909.txt 
But I want only tmp.txt How can I remove appended numeric value?

Comment: Please post the code, but not all of it, just the part where you have isolated the problem. It should be quite easy to remove but without any code I am a little confused as to what the problem exactly is.

Comment: You mean it generated a "random" file name for you? Is that your problem or is the problem how to get the filename generated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove garbage value from a file name which has been created by using createTempFile() method? I need only file name with ext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192701/how-to-remove-garbage-value-from-a-file-name-which-has-been-created-by-using-cre)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.io.File.getName()` method to get name of file..

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      
       File f = null;
            
         // creates temporary file
         try {
            f = File.createTempFile("tmp", ".txt", new File("D:/"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         
         // prints name of temp file
         System.out.println("File name: "+f.getName());
     // prints absolute path
     System.out.println("File path: "+f.getAbsolutePath());
   }
}
```

this will print like

> File name: tmp4501156806082176909.txt
>
> File path: D:\tmp4501156806082176909.txt

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't need a temp file. The purpose of the "garbage" is to protect two or more instances of the app from overwriting each other. In this case use system.getProperty("java.io.temp") to get the temp dir.