# Can I use File.createTempFile() to create a file with a non-random name

Tags: java

I want to create a temporary file (that goes away when the application closes) with a specific name.  I'm using this code:

```
f = File.createTempFile("tmp", ".txt", new File("D:/"));
```

This creates something like `D:\tmp4501156806082176909.txt`.  I want just `D:\tmp.txt`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

In this case, don't use `createTempFile`.  The point of `createTempFile` is to generate the "garbage" name in order to avoid name colisions.

You should use `File.createNewFile()` or simply write to the file.  Whichever is more appropriate for your use case.  You can then call `File.deleteOnExit()` to get the VM to look after cleaning up the file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create just `tmp.txt`, then just create the file using `createNewFile()`, instead of `createTempFile()`. `createTempFile` is used to create temporary files that should not have the same name when created over and over.

Also have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142901/how-to-create-a-file-in-a-directory-in-java) which shows a very simple way to create files.

Taken the post mentioned above:

```
String path = "C:"+File.separator+"hello"+File.separator+"hi.txt";
//(use relative path for Unix systems)
File f = new File(path);
//(works for both Windows and Linux)
f.mkdirs(); 
f.createNewFile();
```

Comment: I don't think it's good practice to use `File.separator` in this way.  It can cause problems with portability (specifically, a class that is compiled on one OS will have File.separator inlined as that OS's value, so it may not work as expected when run on a different OS).  It is better to use `new File(dirName, childName)` which always works.  In your case, `new File(new File("C:", "hello"), "hi.txt");`.  Not sure about `new File("C:")`, I've never tried that (not a regular user of Windows).

Answer (score 1):

try regex

```
fileName = fileName.replaceAll("\\d", "");
```